# Error with shared library with RStudio Server

Tags: r, linux, centos6, rstudio-server

Centos 6.7 machine. Have followed these instructions to install R and RStudio Server:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/

- add EPEL
- install R
- install RStudio Server

However, when trying to start up RStudio I see the following in /var/log/messages:

```
Nov 24 07:39:35 myserver rserver[14346]: ERROR R shared library (/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so) not found. If this is a custom build of R, was it built with the --enable-R-shlib option?; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) /root/rstudio/src/cpp/server/ServerMain.cpp:402
Nov 24 07:39:35 myserver init: rstudio-server main process (14346) terminated with status 1
Nov 24 07:39:35 myserver init: rstudio-server respawning too fast, stopped
```

From a completely fresh install on another machine where these same installation steps work and RStudio fires up without errors, /usr/local/lib64/R/ doesn't even exist, so I'm puzzled why RStudio on the problematic machine is even looking there for the shared libraries...

Stumped! Your suggests appreciated!

Dan

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same problem in the past I remember that i yes had the folder:

> /usr/lib64/R/lib

with the needed libs, so i create a simbolic link:

`ln -s /usr/lib64/R /usr/local/lib64/R`

And it worked well, maybe your case is the same

Comment: nah, that didn't work. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. The problem was caused by an old version of R in another location which was also in my PATH, so starting up RStudio Server was referencing libraries and executables that didn't work, or were incorrect.

My older version of R was in /usr/local/bin and was probably not installed with Yum. All good now!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had three R versions available in my system R2.15.1 and R3.1.0 the third one was installed using alternative option /usr/local/R/3.1.0. I just copied /usr/lib64/R/lib/libR.so to /usr/local/R/3.1.0/lib64/R/lib/ and it worked.